# Duplicate class found modules classes.jar

Tags: java, android, kotlin, url, android-videoview

i am getting this error after implementing this dependency `implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.7'` . i was using `VideoView` but now i want to use ExoPlayer because video is lagging in `VideoView` so i thought this would work . and complete error is something like this .

```
Duplicate class android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel found in modules classes.jar (androidx.core:core:1.0.1) and classes.jar (com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2)
```

i try to find some solution but most of answer says to remove one of dependency . i can not remove one of them . i want both . so what i can do in this condition ?

**EDIT 1 :**

i did something like this

```
implementation('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.7'){
        exclude group: 'androidx.core' , module : 'core'
        exclude group: 'androidx.media' , module : 'media'
    }
```

and now i don't have those conflict errors but now i am getting some new error here it is :

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): java.lang.CharSequence com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager$MediaDescriptionAdapter.getCurrentSubText(com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
Invoke-customs are only supported starting with Android O (--min-api 26)

Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): java.lang.CharSequence com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerNotificationManager$MediaDescriptionAdapter.getCurrentSubText(com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player)

AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): void com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player$EventListener.onIsPlayingChanged(boolean)","sources":[{}],"tool":"D8"}
Default interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): void com.google.android.exoplayer2.Player$EventListener.onIsPlayingChanged(boolean)
```

i tried to update my `minSdkVersion` to 24 and they were gone becuase we have lots user below 24 , i try to find solution on the web but it gives me forum in Chinese and i don't understand Chinese
Thank You in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You would need to exclude one of the dependencies from importing the package.

So change either

```
implementation ('com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.11.7')
{ 
exclude module : 'android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel'
}
```

or

```
implementation ('androidx.core:core:1.0.1')
{ exclude module : 'android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel'
}
```

Comment: i tried as you illustrate , but it is not working giving same error