# Lost connection to device. After add video_player packages in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, video, video-player, flutter-video-player

I have project flutter, and I want to add the live-streaming feature to this project. I want to use video_player packages (https://pub.dev/packages/video_player/versions/2.0.0-nullsafety.3) but after I have added the packages I get an error in my project.

### Flutter Doctor

hesa@hesa-dev:~/Documents/FlutterAPP/SiakTV_RPK-hs1$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
• Flutter version 2.2.3 at /home/hesa/snap/flutter/common/flutter
• Framework revision f4abaa0735 (12 days ago), 2021-07-01 12:46:11 -0700
• Engine revision 241c87ad80
• Dart version 2.13.4

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
• Android SDK at /home/hesa/Android/Sdk/
• Platform android-S, build-tools 30.0.3
• Java binary at: /home/hesa/Downloads/android-studio/jre/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821)
• All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
• Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
• Android Studio at /home/hesa/Downloads/android-studio
• Flutter plugin version 58.0.1
• Dart plugin version 202.8531
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+0-b944-P17168821)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.0)
• VS Code at /usr/share/code
• Flutter extension version 3.24.0

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
• SM A315G (mobile) • RR8N604V1BL • android-arm64  • Android 11 (API 30)
• Chrome (web)      • chrome      • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.106

• No issues found!

[Image Console project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zp1kq.png)

Comment: Are you connected your device with USB port? if so, it might be disconnected.

Comment: Yes already connected to a real device, this issue (lost connection to device) has been fixed, I have a new issue with the same packages (video_player).
the console in the comments below;

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> 1 exception was raised by workers:
  java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.package-info found in modules jetified-exoplayer-common-2.14.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-common:2.14.1) and jetified-exoplayer-ui-2.11.1-runtime.jar (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.11.1)

  Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63283086/duplicate-class-found-modules-classes-jar. This might help you, checkout

Comment: I didn't find a solution in this link references, the problem is not solved

Comment: when adding the video_player package there is always a problem with exoplayer2. and Lost connection to device when I'm running the project.

Comment: It's the problem with conflicting libs. Kindly check the dependency jars.

Comment: I just solved it, done... the problem in this project I use radio_package and video_player. it makes exoplayer2 always conflict, I solved it by removing one of the packages.